# Compare two dates in DB2, to know if it is different from current date

Tags: javascript, sql, database, db2

I need to compare a date to know if they are a different day from today, one from my database and the other is the current date, but when i get the date it quits a day, month and year still ok but day not.

```
var datecheck = result.invocationResult.resultSet[0].CHECKINDATE;
 var d = new Date(datecheck);
 var n = d.getDate();   
 console.log(n);
```

![my date in the DB2 looks like this]

CHECKINDATE":2014-08-07T00:00:00.000Z"

Comment: Why the HTML and SQLite tags? And what language is this?

Comment: Any why the lack of javascript tags?

Comment: `date it quits a day, month and year still ok but day no` I don't understand

Comment: Also, keep in mind that JavaScript give you the local time of the client machine, the DB will give you the server.  You can never rely on both being the same, or in the same timezone.

Comment: i found the answer with this query:                                                         SELECT *
FROM   table
WHERE MYDATE  = CURRENT DATE;

Comment: i found the answer with this query:


 SELECT * FROM table WHERE MYDATE = CURRENT DATE;

So with this i only select the values in my databse that are from today

Comment: i found the answer with this query:


 SELECT * FROM table WHERE MYDATE = CURRENT DATE;

So with this i only select the values in my databse that are from today

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to your question you want rows where the date is different from today, in your comment you propose the solution:

```
 SELECT * FROM table WHERE MYDATE = CURRENT DATE
```

Given the formulation of the problem I would expect:

```
 SELECT * FROM table WHERE MYDATE <> CURRENT_DATE
```

to be closure to the truth.